# Problema con integración listas en Python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente y ojalá alguien pudiera ayudarme:

```py
A=[A,B,C,D,A,A,A,B,B,C,C]
B=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]   #cada elemento de B corresponde en su orden a uno de A
```

Quisiera que en otra lista llamada `C` me mostrara la lista `A` sin variables repetidas y en orden y en otra lista `D` se sumen los valores de `B` para la misma variable de `A`, es decir, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```py
C=[A,B,C,D]
D=[19,19,6,4] #(los valores correspondientes a A son (1+5+6+7) B(2+8+9) C(3+1+2) D(4)
```

Agradezco su amable ayuda.

Comment: las variables que aparecen en la lista `A` son las que haz puesto mas abajo?

Comment: Sí. La lista C recoge todos los valores de A en orden y eliminando repetidos.

Comment: y D recoge la suma de los elementos repetidos en A de acuerdo a su posición. Por ejemplo, en la lista A la letra A se encuentra en las posiciones 0,4,5,6. Y en esas mismas posiciones en B se encuentran los valores 1,5,6,7. Sumando estos valores (1+5+6+7) obtengo que para A en la lista C tengo 19 en la lista D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una pregunta muy interesante, tendrás `+1` cuando publique la respuesta.

Como muestras una lista `A=[A,B,C,D,A,A,A,B,B,C,C]` y los elementos son tomados como variables en Python, tendremos errores, así que la lista con la que trabajaremos será

```
A=["A","B","C","D","A","A","A","B","B","C","C"]
```

También necesitaremos una función del modulo `functools`, llamada `reduce`. Bueno vamos con el código.

```py
from functools import reduce #importamos la funcion

A=["A","B","C","D","A","A","A","B","B","C","C"]
B=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]
```

Para obtener las variables que no están repetidas podemos hacer uso de `set()`, de esta forma

```
C = list(set(A)) #convertimos a lista el resultado de set()
print(C)
#salida-> ['D', 'B', 'C', 'A']
```

Esto es correcto, pero no están en orden, para eso solo le aplicamos la función `sorted()` la cual ordena los elementos de un iterable. Quedando asi

```py
C = sorted(list(set(A)))
print(C)
#salida-> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Para obtener la variable `D` haremos uso de la función `reduce` Esto simplifica mucho el trabajo y hace más eficiente el proceso. Pero para obtener la información de  las posiciones tendremos que unir ambas listas eso lo hacemos c9n la función `zip()`

```py
#unimos para sacar los valores
union_AB = list(zip(A,B))
#print(union_AB)

#obtenemos datos como diccionarios 
pre_data = reduce(lambda C, i: {**C, union_AB[i][0]:C.get(union_AB[i][0], 0) + union_AB[i][1]}, range(len(union_AB)), {})

#obtenemos variable D
D = list(pre_data.values())
print(D)
```

**Resultado**

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
[19, 19, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Muy agradecido con la ayuda Christian.  Saludos.

Comment: denada, es un placer ayudar y recuerda aceptar cualquiera de las 2 respuesta si alguna resolvió tu problema :)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primero hay que declarar bien la listas:

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
A=['A','B','C','D','A','A','A','B','B','C','C']
B=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]
```

Creo un diccionario vacío para agregar la letras y la suma de sus valores

```
dic={}


for x in range(len(A)):
    dic.setdefault(A[x],0)
    dic[A[x]]+=B[x]
```

Recorro la lista y creo una clave con cada letra, definida por su posición en la lista A y con valor 0, después le sumo a cada letra su valor definido por la posición en la lista B

```
C=sorted(set(A))
```

la lista C es una lista ordenada de un conjunto(evita duplicados) de A

```
D=[dic.get(C[x]) if x != 0 else dic.get(C[1]) for x in range(len(C)) ]
```

por último creo una lista por comprensión de listas que de acuerdo al indice toma el valor del diccionario antes creado

```
print(C)
print(D)
```

Esto muestra:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
[19, 19, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Agradezco la amable colaboración tincopasan.  Saludos.